# use return value in parameter of another function jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, parameters, scope

I trie to get the result of this function :

```
var isLaptop = false;
function is1024up() {   
    $(window).on('load resize', function() {
        isLaptop = $(window).width() > 1024;
    });
    return isLaptop;
} 

lap = is1024up(); // I put the result of my function in a global
```

I would like to use the result of this function on parameter of another function

```
function test(lap){
    console.log(lap); //the result don't change on resize
    if (lap) {
      // my code here
    }

}
```

My issue is on the resize function : I can get the result on `is1024up()` when the page load but this result isn't uptable on resize.

Any idea ?

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it with `return`. Use the `resize` event to just update the variable. Use the `isLaptop` variable just everywhere to read the current state.

```
var isLaptop = false;

$(window).on('load resize', function() {
    isLaptop = $(window).width() > 1024;
});

function test() {
    console.log(isLaptop);
}
```

Comment: I would like to organize my code like this because I test a lot of time if this `is1024up` is true or not. I would like to not repeat always `$(window).on('load resize', function() {});`

Comment: Hmm. Okay. I've updated my answer. @BrownBe

Comment: Strangely, this is does't work... @eisbehr

Comment: Why? It is working fine. https://jsfiddle.net/o6agksm6/ @BrownBe

Comment: oh, yes it works. it was simpler than thought. Thanks @eisbehr.